# Embed a Powershell Window inside a Winforms form

Tags: c#, powershell

Is it possible to embed a Powershell screen in my application?

I want to see the screen itself, just like Visual Studio does. I cannot use a console redirect as that option would not allow me to interact with programs or view programs displaying colors and the like.

Capture both standard input and standard output is not a possible solution. I am using programs that use colors and progress bars.

It would be something similar to being able to implement a [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), or https://github.com/dwmkerr/consolecontrol

I also tried this code, but it does not allow me to embed to Terminal server although I can use it with Notepad [Run extended programs GUI on my own c# form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764526/run-extended-programs-gui-on-my-own-c-sharp-form)

Looking for information, I found a project that apparently could be what I am looking for but it does not work with Winforms and I cannot find a simple example of use. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices

Comment: Yes.  You need to capture both standard input and standard output.

Comment: Check out this question and the multiple answers. There is a linked example for doing this with winforms even though it focuses on WPF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284500/embed-a-console-window-inside-a-wpf-window

Comment: @Cpt.Whale The solutions listed are not valid. The code I use does not capture the powershell window and the option to use the stardand input / output is not valid because it would not correctly display the colors and progress.

Comment: @VictorSanchez [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-sharp-program) that would be useful?

Comment: @zaggler this code is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764526/run-extended-programs-gui-on-my-own-c-sharp-form with powershell.exe don't work. I think that code does not work with console applications such as poowershell.